# Is there a way to check if a query is finished executing when using the SQL API?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

lets say I have a script that sends a query using the built in SQL API and it's being run asynchronously. Is there any way of getting snowflake to notify me that the query has been finished and is ready for my script to retrieve the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the doc here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/guide.html#checking-the-status-of-the-statement-execution-and-retrieving-the-data

> To check if the statement has finished executing, **you must send a request to check the status of the statement**.

So I guess the answer to your question is No, Snowflake will NOT notify users when query is finished. User has to check themselves.